# Invalid column name on stored procedure

Tags: c#, wpf, stored-procedures, syntax-error, sql-server-2014-express

Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelectUserFromProfileUsers]
    @TableName NVARCHAR(20),
    @User NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE  Users =' + @User

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
END
```

and here is my code in Visual Studio:

```
if (TableFunctions.doesTableExist(ComboBoxSelectedProfile.SelectedItem + "Users", dbConnectionString))
{
    // DynamicSQL
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spSelectUserFromProfileUsers", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", ComboBoxSelectedProfile.SelectedItem + "Users");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", TextBoxUserName.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the error:

> Invalid column name /Text that I entered the textbox/

I've been looking for a solution a long time and I can't find anything, I'll appreciate your help very much!

Comment: The result of your concatenation would be something like this: `SELECT * from [YourTable] WHERE Users = Some_User_Name`....see the problem?, `Some_User_Name` should be `'Some_User_Name'`

Comment: but if i add '@User' it won't recgnize the @User as parameter

Comment: And this code is still open ti sql injection security vulnerabilities since you are just using concatenation inside the sproc.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway so how would you do it to prevent SQLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `Users` value is inside quotes. As it's a `sql` and there are only single quotes available, you have to do it in that strange way.

```
SET @query='SELECT * from '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' where Users='''+@User+''''
```

Comment: it did work but it is hard for me to understand why beacuse of the many quottes marks.

Comment: '''' because to set ' between ' ' would not be possible, tjere is option to add one more, and sql interprets it as it should. Simillar situation is here: '''.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure that tries to execute a dynamic sql has a wrong syntax.

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @query='SELECT * from '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' where Users=@User';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@User NVARCHAR(20)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition, @User = @User;
```

From the [documentation about sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) you could see that a parameter should be used as is inside the dynamic sql text not trying to extract is value and appending the value. After that you should define the parameter for the sp_executesql (`@ParmDefinition`) and set its value (`@User = @User`) as second and third parameter to sp_executesql

Answer (score -1):

query is not properly enclosed.

```
    SET @query="SELECT * from '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' where Users='+@User+'"
```

Comment: that will work in `c#` but no in `sql` as there is no double-quote there.

Comment: Sorry my bad there should be single quote. though issue is same.